# Which apps do gapless music playback?

Tags: applications, music, audio, mp3-player

Are there any apps around that are good at gapless audio playback? I listen to a lot of music that continues from one track to another and the stock app puts a small but noticeable gap between tracks.

Comment: I'd be interested as well, I get so annoyed by the jarring split-second of silence.

Comment: In the interim, I've decided to join the files together with http://www.makeitone.net/audio/mp3albummaker.htm ... would prefer to get this sorted though.

Answer (score 3):

Try the latest [Museek](https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.ethz.dcg.pancho2) player. It has support for gapless playback. You need to enable it from within the ADVANCED settings in the app.

There's also [PowerAmp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) and [Winamp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp) which seemingly offer decent gapless playback quality.

Comment: Thanks. PowerAmp and Museek claim to have gapless, but the music I've used to test this didn't play that way and fiddling with the settings didn't help. Winamp doesn't do gapless at all. The forums for PowerAmp claim that true gapless is in the works.For the record, Winamp on Windows plays the music seamlessly.

Answer (score -1):

The *Amazon MP3* player adds gaps. Luckily you can play songs downloaded to the device with any music player, and *Google Music* does gapless playback out of the box.

Comment: Re Google Music: I wonder if that's a per album thing? I used it to download Black Sabbath's first album to my device and going from one track to the next still had a gap.

Comment: @MarkHewitt: do you have other albums that Google Music plays without gaps? So far it seems to work fine for the Jean-Michel Jarre albums I've played.

Comment: Can you give me a specific example that I can test? I'm assuming this is an album available in All Access?

Comment: @MarkHewitt It's music from Amazon's Cloudplayer. I don't recall the specific example right now, I just noticed that Google Music played it better than Amazon MP3.